# Netflix Composting Support

Tags: netflix-desktop

I receive this message when trying to open Netflix Desktop.

Compositing is not available, please enable compositing support and relaunch Netflix Desktop.

How do I enable compositing support for Netflix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error that indicates you did not install a driver that supports it:

[From a bugreport on netflix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netflix-desktop/+bug/1214355/comments/6):

1. Go to the power/config menu in the upper right and choose "System Settings".
2. Open "Additional Drivers"
3. Choose the most up-to-date proprietary driver it lists that is not labeled "experimental"
4. Click "Activate"
5. Wait for it to download and activate the driver
6. Try again. If it does not work then reboot and try again ;)